# What is the recommended layout for splitting ternary operator into multiple lines?

Tags: python, pycharm, indentation, ternary-operator, pep8

To improve code readability I need to split my ternary operator expression into multiple lines. My only idea is something like this:

```
very_long_function_name(
    ...
    very_long_expression_if_the_condition_is_true
      if the_condition
      else another_expression_if_the_condition_is_false)
```

Unfortunately PyCharm claims that `continuation line over-indented for visual indent` is a violation of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). When I wrap the operator in braces PyCharm raises no objections, but IMHO the code is less readable then.

Is there any [semi]formal recommendation for splitting ternary operator into multiple lines?

Declaration of auxiliary functions/methods is not an option.

Comment: If you are concerned about readability, I'd start by using a name for the argument, setting the name with the long conditional expression before the call.

Comment: @chepner I like your suggestion, +1. Unfortunately the actual problem is that one of the expressions is the method parameter (it is fixed API) with long, meaningful name.

Comment: Unless its a parameter name for a keyword argument, you can always just define a new variable with a shorter name and the same value (`short_name = long_name`). Even if it *is* a parameter name, you can pass it via a dict (`short_name="long_name"; func(**{short_name}: value}`) instead. It's hard to provide any good advice without more detail about what's actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

Code formatting is generally too much of a matter of opinion, so I think [Opinionated and automated code formatting](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/opinionated-and-automated-code-formatting) is the solution - install and run [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) and cease talking about it.

Comment: That is exactly why I am looking for [semi]formal recommendations (like pep-8). However would take a look at _black_, thanks!

Comment: Here's how I do it: https://github.com/brunns/brunns-matchers/blob/master/tox.ini#L125